# how to get specific data from json file using python

Tags: python, json

this is my code below

```
from pybit import HTTP
    import json
    
    session = HTTP("https://api.bybit.com",api_key=xxxx, api_secret=xxxx)
    g=session.get_wallet_balance(coin="USDT")
    data=json.dumps(g,indent=4)
    print(data)
    for result in data ['USDT']:
        print(["equity"])
```

keep getting type error like this

```
    for result in data ['USDT']:
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Comment: Use breakpoints and step through the code. Data is apparently not a dictionary (but rather a string). If you want a little bit more robust code, add error handling as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
    data=json.dumps(g,indent=4)
```

This serializes the dict `g` into a string using the JSON format. Don't do that!

In fact, you don't need `import json` at all because `pybit` has already parsed the JSON response from the  HTTP request, so you don't need to do anything. Instead, you should use `g` directly: `g['USDT']`. Better yet, just rename `g` to `data`:

```
data = session.get_wallet_balance(coin="USDT")
```